# Ansible: Undefined Variable

Tags: ansible, cisco, ansible-facts

I am defining a variable via set_fact: but during debug, it shows as undefined.

Code:

```
---
- name: Looppback Info
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: switch
  connection: local
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Gather Switch Info
      ios_facts:

    - set_fact:
        loopback = {{ ansible_facts["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"][0]["address"] }}

    - name: Debug
      debug:
       var: loopback
...
```

Error:

```
TASK [Debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.119.128.4] => {
    "loopback": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: If there is a question, like "Are there altneratives to Ansible on which my configuration works without throwing an error?", or "If I reprogram this in BASIC to circumvent the error, how can I read the YAML document?", you should edit your post and include that question.

Comment: I am using Ansible as stated in the title - I need to register the var in YAML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error

```
- set_fact:
    loopback = {{ ansible_facts ...
```

Correct syntax is

```
- set_fact:
    loopback: "{{ ansible_facts ...
```

Comment: When I edit it as such:

    - set_fact:
        loopback: "{{ ansible_facts["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"][0]["address"] }}"

It gives a syntax in my code.

Comment: Follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```html
    - set_fact:
        loopback: "{{ ansible_facts.net_interfaces.Loopback0.ipv4.0.address }}"
```

This fixed it. Had to switch to this formatting.